# scan more than 10 images in one bitmap using ML Kit

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I am using Firebase Ml Kit on Android (firebase-ml-vision-barcode) to process bitmaps of scanned student tests with aztez and qr codes that has a lot of codes on them  evrything works well except that it gets back always not more than 10 barcode even if there are 40 on one bitmap, is there a way to change detector options to get more than 10 detected, or If it is impossible is there a way to divide on the basis of lines in picture (as visible in sample below  codes are localized in table)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KsvvPtzHDFjsXEgi1yq0pNXwQmtU58Xq
below function that i Use

> private    val options =
>   FirebaseVisionBarcodeDetectorOptions.Builder()
>           .setBarcodeFormats(FirebaseVisionBarcode.FORMAT_ALL_FORMATS).build()
>   private  val detector =
>   FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options)
>
> /**
>        * get data encoded in barcodes qr codes and aztec codes from pdf of given id in google drive and pushes it to appropriate spreadsheet
>        * @param fileId id of google drive file (PDF file) that we want to analyze
>        * */
>        suspend fun getDataFromPDFInGdrive (fileId: String){
>           println("getDataFromPDFInGdrive $fileId  ")
>           managePDF.pdfToBitmaps(fileId){
>               bitMap ->
>               val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitMap)
>               val result = detector.detectInImage(image)
>                   .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
>                       GlobalScope.launch { analyzeBarcodeData(barcodes)}            }
>           }
>       }

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out I am drawing black squares on bitmap evry time ml kit find aztec code on the bitmap in the coordinations given by firebase ml kit and then repeating the process

```
      /**
     * recurrently analyzes the data from  the bitmap  it first checks weather we have any codes in bitmap if we have it adds them to result
     * then it invokes function that paints black squere in position of the code and scans it one more time
     * - it is a workaround for limitation of ma kit that it enables to scan no more than 10 picture at a time
     * */
    tailrec  suspend fun getAllCodes (
        bitMap: Bitmap,
        listPrim: List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>,
        canvas: Canvas
    ) : List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>  {
        val newList = fromBitMapToBarcodeImages (bitMap)
        addBlackSquareInCodePlace(bitMap,newList,canvas)

if (newList.isEmpty()) {
    return listPrim.union(newList).toList()
}
 //executed if new list is not empty

    return  getAllCodes (bitMap, listPrim.union(newList).toList(),canvas)
    }


    /**
     *adds a black square in place of a scanned code and  gives back midified bitmap
     * */
suspend fun addBlackSquareInCodePlace(
        bitMap: Bitmap,
        listOfBarCodeData: List<FirebaseVisionBarcode>,
        canvas: Canvas
    ) : Bitmap{
        pushBitmapToDrive(bitMap,"aswa"+ listOfBarCodeData.size,"1r6peFVJfcXM0KCDJUt-_QNP_RS8JAl65")

        listOfBarCodeData.forEach {
            it.boundingBox?.let { it1 -> canvas.drawRect(it1,paint) };
        }
        return bitMap

    }
```